# Write/Read with High Replication Datastore + NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

So I have been reading a lot of documentation on HRD and NDB lately, yet I still have some doubts regarding how NDB caches things.

**Example case:**

Imagine a case where a users writes data and the app needs to fetch it immediately after the write. E.g. A user creates a "Group" (similar to a Facebook/Linkedin group) and is redirected to the group immediately after creating it. *(For now, I'm creating a group without assigning it an ancestor)*

**Result:**

When testing this sort of functionality locally (having enabled high replication), the immediate fetch of the newly created group fails. A NoneType is returned.

**Question:**

Having gone through the High Replication docs and Google IO videos, I understand that there is a higher write latency, however, shouldn't NDB caching take care of this? I.e. A write is cached, and then asynchronously actually written on disk, therefore, an immediate read would be reading from cache and thus there should be no problem. Do I need to enforce some other settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you are running into the HRD feature where queries are "eventually consistent".  NDB's caching has nothing to do with this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it might be because of the redirect that the NoneType is returned.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#incontext

> The in-context cache persists only for the duration of a single incoming HTTP request and is "visible" only to the code that handles that request. It's fast; this cache lives in memory. When an NDB function writes to the Datastore, it also writes to the in-context cache. When an NDB function reads an entity, it checks the in-context cache first. If the entity is found there, no Datastore interaction takes place.
>   Queries do not look up values in any cache. However, query results are written back to the in-context cache if the cache policy says so (but never to Memcache).

So you are writing the value to the cache, redirecting it and the read then fails because the HTTP request on the redirect is a different one and so the cache is different.

I'm reaching the limit of my knowledge here but I'd suggest initially that you try the create in a transaction and redirect when complete/success.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions

Also when you put the group model into the datastore you'll get a key back. Can you pass that key (via urlsafe for example) to the redirect and then you'll be guaranteed to retrieve the data as you have it's explicit key? Can't have it's key if it's not in the datastore after all.

Also I'd suggest trying it as is on the production server, sometimes behaviours can be very different locally and on production.

Comment: Thanks. The HTTP request issue with in-context caching makes sense. However, turning it into a transactional operation does not solve the problem. Correct me if I'm wrong, but Datastore returns a Key before it is written on disk. This is why even though I get a key, when I get() it, it returns a NoneType. I'm guessing that a workaround may be to memcache it for a couple of seconds... Is this a good solution?

Comment: Reading this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Datastore_Writes_and_Data_Visibility it also says "Because Datastore gets and ancestor queries apply any outstanding modifications before executing, these operations always see a consistent view of all previous successful transactions. This means that a get operation (looking up an updated entity by its key) is guaranteed to see the latest version of that entity." So as far as I can tell you should not get noneType after doing a get with a key that was generated from a put.

Comment: Thanks. I think that with "consistent" GAE is referring to that there is no partially updated data floating around the system. I _think_ this does not imply data is written when the key is returned. I've done some more testing, and when I update a value and dont redirect to a page, I immediately see the new value (it's coming from in-context cache). However, when I update and redirect, the value is not updated on the first page load (due to the HTTP request issue you mentioned). Only when I reload (it has had time to write to disk) do I see the updated value.

Comment: this is strange, as I often redirect to content that the user has just created and it's *always* there. Then I suggest dropping the content into memcache explicitly and getting it back out again on the next request, even if ndb will also be caching.

Comment: And the reason as to why I'm redirecting is to avoid the annoying "confirm reload page" alert when yo try to reload a page after a HTTP POST, and thus resends POST data...

Comment: out of interest, how large is the data you are writing? my use cases have been quite small so perhaps...

Comment: Are you using custom cache policies or are you running on default settings?

Comment: Are you running locally with High Replication enabled? Without High Replication I'm not getting this issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16557/discussion-between-paul-c-and-m12)